# Is Flight SQL similar to a library like turbodbc?

Tags: apache-arrow

I was curious if Flight SQL will be an alternative to libraries like turbodbc? I am using turbodbc to query many different database flavors to return data in a pyarrow table, but I have had to add the OBDC drivers to my Docker image.

Is this something that can be used to query databases as a read-only user, or would something need to be done server side to support Flight SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flight SQL requires something database-side, yes. It's lower level than something like ODBC or JDBC, which (for instance) don't specify anything about the wire protocol; instead, it's a set of libraries intended to be used with a particular RPC protocol.

That said, it is intended to support use cases like yours. It's just that implementations are forthcoming (and things like Python bindings). Reaching out on the Arrow mailing list may get some more attention: [dev@arrow.apache.org](https://arrow.apache.org/community/)

UPDATE 2022/07: the more direct alternative to something like turbodbc, ODBC, JDBC, etc. in the Arrow ecosystem is under development as "ADBC": https://github.com/apache/arrow-adbc This is an API abstraction layer, so it doesn't require a remote server or local proxy, so long as you can somehow bend the database (client) to the proposed API.

Comment: So it sounds like something I will be able to implement for databases I control, but perhaps not for clients where I only have read-access (it is hard enough to get that, let alone have them change configurations etc). I am waiting for the Python bindings so I can test, thanks!

Comment: Well, you could always implement a local proxy, though that may not be ideal.

Comment: I didn't notice your update, but I happened to naturally find my way to the arrow_odbc library and I have happily been using it for several months.